# Write Characteristics Android BLE app cant see the results

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

i've a problem with write and reading from a BLE device.
I've tried with "BLE utils" app (on iOS app store) and with this app i can write and see the result on RealTerm software that i use to check the results on my BLE device.
But if ill do with my Android app, and with this method:
(I've one button for scan + discover services + search characteristics, and one more button for send string to the Characteristics with WRITE property)

```
public boolean writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, String text) {

    if (MainActivity.myBluetoothAdapter == null || FragmentOne.bluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w("WRITE", "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return false;
    }

    byte tx = (byte) Integer.parseInt(text);
    byte[] ch = new byte[1];

    ch[0] = tx;

    characteristic.setValue(ch);
    characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
    return FragmentOne.bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
}
```

And this method will call:

```
@Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        Log.d("Connect","------------- onCharacteristicWrite status: " + status);

        // do somethings here.
    }
```

In the last one, the result value it's 0, but i cant see the value on RealTerm like the iOS app.
What im doing wrong?

EDIT 1:
This is the Log after press the send button.

> 08-01 10:37:59.122 602-602/ D/BluetoothGatt: writeCharacteristic() - uuid: 7fb03169-d527-4ca8-b9f0-c6f4a887c2fa
>   08-01 10:37:59.152 602-602/ D/RESULT: Val : true
>   08-01 10:37:59.152 602-940/ D/BluetoothGatt: onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=00:07:80:C0:4B:E9 UUID=7fb03169-d527-4ca8-b9f0-c6f4a887c2fa Status=0
>   08-01 10:37:59.152 602-940/ D/Connect: ------------- onCharacteristicWrite status: 0

EDIT 2:
@zomb

```
@Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
        Log.i("onServicesDiscovered", services.toString());
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = null;

        for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
            Log.d("SERVICE","Service with address: " + service.getUuid());

            characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
            for(BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch : characteristics)
            {
                Log.d("CHAR","Has characteristic with adress: " + ch.getUuid());

                if (((ch.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) | ( ch.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE)) > 0) {
                    // writing characteristic functions
                    //Here it's where ill save the various Uuid of services and characteristics.

                    Log.d("WRITECHAR", "WRITE UUID : " + ch.getUuid());

                }
                else if((ch.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0)
                {
                 //And Here...
                    Log.d("READCHAR","READ UUID : " + ch.getUuid());

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

After many attempts I saved to a file different UUIDs of various services & characterics.

Comment: How are you getting the characteristic that you pass into the function writeCharacteristic? Is it from the service?

Comment: I've edited the first post to answer you @Zomb

Comment: Thank you. I assume you are using the discovered characteristic and not creating a new one when you call write characteristic. Have you tried using an app like BLE Scanner from the play store to see if you can write to the characteristic?

Comment: @Zomb, ty man, i've found an app that show to me one characteristics with notifications, and when i enable this one, i can finally write with success :D
Now i have to search how to read from the device, but even with the other app on PlayStore, i cant read. :/

Comment: But you are able to read using the iOS app?

Comment: From the iOS app, yes.

Comment: same issue i also have please anybody help me for this